# excel 2016: how to sort a column when the column cells are the sum of 5 adjacent cells

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I am trying to sort **col A**. The Cell **A1** is `sum(B1 + C1 + D1 +E1)`.
This is a scoring system where **col 'A'** is the total.

Each of B1/etc is the result of an `IF` statement evaluating ranges elsewhere in the worksheet. B1/etc will range from +/- 2, +/- 1, 0. So, a given cell in col'A' can range from +8 to -8.

**problem:** I find that sorting a column with an embedded formula [like the 'sum' formula] is not accurate, i might get +8, +8, +3, -3, +7, etc. if i copy/paste cell values from the sum into a spare column, then a sort of largest to smallest, the sort result is accurate.

i don't understand what is happening. so i am having some trouble trying to fix this.
again, i am sorting rows in a 'table', using the values in cells in 1 column, where each cell in the column is a sum of 4 adjacent cells in the same row [this sum is done row by row via formula; the 'table' propagates the formula down the rows].

seems simple enough; but i can't figure out what is the root cause.

thanks,
ron

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand you correctly here. Basically, you just want to numerically sort the results of a formula on a spreadsheet where the numbers are on column 'A'?

For some reason it isnt working for you?

Regardless, here is what I came up with, let me know if I am off or need more work:

Starting with cell A2 and continuing with the rest of column A's formulas change them to this:

In `Cell A2`, the formula would be: `=Sum(B2:E2)`.

In `Cell A3`, the formula would be: `=Sum(B3:E3)`.

And continue on with that down the rest of the columns

Once finished, put a title in `Cell A1`, go to your `Data Tab` and click the Filter button, from there you can then click on the drop down button in `Cell A1`then select the filter option that you need (IE: Smallest to Largest, or Largest to Smallest).

See screenshot below:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOkAP.png)

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: hi DEG, let me add:  B/C/D/E are the result of IF statements. when i sort, the results are not uniform. i did a PERCENTRANK on col A and worked fine. i may have issues using relative addressing where i should use absolute addressing. i suspect i need to do some homework on cell addressing options. anyway, thanks for responding, it is helping push me back to learning.